# Reshape pandas dataframe from column to unique index

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to reshape my dataframe, in which I want the `Person` to the be index, however how do I make it so the index is unique?  I don't know want duplicates in my Index.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Person':['Paul','Paul','Paul','John','John','Mia'],'Score':[24,23,54,64,89,56],'Type':['A','C','F','A','G','X'],'Number':[1,2,3,1,2,1]})

df.set_index('Person',inplace = True)
```

Desired output:

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you want to handle duplicate values. Do you want to create a list of values, a mean, choose one, etc.?

Comment: Do a `reset_index()` before `set_index()` and then `set_index(['Person', 'index'])`   ?

Comment: I just want to set the column `Person` into the index, but when I set it, there are duplicates, I just want there to be 1 index value for that group. I displayed that in the picture above.

Comment: Yes, but you have 3 scores for Paul, how should those scores be combined? Or should they stay separate?

Comment: If `Number` is unique under each Person, then make a MultiIndex on `Person` and `Number` ?

Comment: I think you have taken a wrong choice of taking some blank values as index!  You are duplicating in another (hidden) sense:  blank index are duplicated !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just wanna remove the duplicate values from the index use:

```
df = df.set_index('Person')
df.index = np.where(df.index.duplicated(), '', df.index)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a `MultiIndex`, keeping the previous numerical index as the second level:

```py
df.set_index(['Person', df.index], inplace=True)
df
```

```
            Score   Type    Number
Person              
Paul    0   24      A       1
        1   23      C       2
        2   54      F       3
John    3   64      A       1
        4   89      G       2
Mia     5   56      X       1
```

I think this is the closest you can get to your desired output, because by definition there has to be an index value for each row of the dataframe.